# htaccess - rewriterule help needed

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having problem with my rewrite rules. I have some urls with variables which look like this: `localhost/mysite/user.php?u=username`. I want to convert them to this: `localhost/mysite/user/username/`

**This is what I have tried**

```
RewriteRule  ^user/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    /mysite/user.php?u=$1    [NC,L]    
# Handle user page requests
```

but its not working :(

`/mysite/user.php` is in htdocs folder (because I am in local environment)

If somehow url like this opened `localhost/user.php?u=username` it should redirect or change to `localhost/user/username/`, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `/mysite/.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /user\.php\?u=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ user/%1/? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)[^/][?\s]
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^user/([^/.]+)/$ user.php?u=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: That is not enough information. Where is this htaccess located? Where is user.php located and what URL do you see in browser for 404?

Comment: this is the url where `object not found` `http://localhost/user/hsn0`

and my .htaccess file is in `htdocs/mysite/.htaccess`

Comment: yes .htaccess is located in `/mysite/` and `http://localhost/mysite/user/hsn0/` this I want

Comment: this is redirect to `http://localhost/mysite/user/hsn0/?u=hsn0` :( and whole document is spoiled

Comment: also tested in new browser same happens :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76247/discussion-between-anubhava-and-hsn0331).